# How to write TIMESTAMPDIFF in a codeigniter sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

In phpmyadmin I can run this query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,first_load,last_load) AS uptime FROM table
```

but how do I write that query in the codeignitor way? That doesn't work:

```
$this->db->select('TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,first_load,last_load) AS uptime')
```

The real query is a bit more complex, so I was showing only one part. This would be the full query (not working):

```
$this->db
 ->select('n.unique_id, n.name, b.impressions, b.clicks, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,first_load,last_load) AS uptime')
 ->from(self::$_table . ' AS b')
 ->join('sm_names AS n', 'n.id = b.name_id AND n.blocked = \'0\' AND n.unique_id != 11111111')
 ->where('b.last_load >', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - (86400 * 2)))
 ->order_by($order, 'desc')
 ->limit($limit);
```

It generates this error message: http://screencast.com/t/ZUYq58Rc6uA

Thanks.

Comment: It turned out that you can't use the active record pattern, you need to type it in a pure sql commant.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a space after last_load in `TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,first_load,last_load)` before the bracket closes.